# WCF Endpoint not found when invoking wcf service from URL

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have created WCF service.And i have created two normal methods which are non-parameter method.But i have created one new method but this time it require two parameters.And the method is like

**Interface:**

```
[OperationContract]     
[WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "GetClassCode/{name}/{password}")]
int GetAuthenticatedUserData(string name, string password);
```

**.Cs**

```
 public int GetAuthenticatedUserData(string name, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=HITSEDGE\HITSEDGE;Initial Catalog=CCIL1;User ID=dbassist;Password=assist@123"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name,Password from dbo.[CCIL$ADCS User] where Name=" + name + " and password" + password, con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    if (dt != null)
                    {
                        return 1;
                    }
                    else
                        return 0;
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }



    }
```

And my web.config is like

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <!--<basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NewBinding0" />
      </basicHttpBinding>-->
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ExtendedMaxSize"
            maxBufferSize="999999" maxReceivedMessageSize="999999" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="crossDomain" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"></binding>
      </webHttpBinding>

    </bindings>
    <services>
      <!--<service name="MyService.MyService">
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0" contract="MyService.IMyService" />
      </service>-->

      <service name="MyService.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyService.IMyService" name="MyService.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="AjaxBehavior"  bindingConfiguration="crossDomain">

          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>


      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DefaultBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="AjaxBehavior">
          <webHttp></webHttp>
          <!--<webHttp helpEnabled="true" />-->
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

      <!--<serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          -->
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
      <!--
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          -->
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <!--
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>-->
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

But when i invoke my parameter method through URL like below url i got error **Endpoint not found.**

**URL**

Localhost/MyService.svc/GetAuthenticatedUserData?name='Himansu'&password='hits@123'

Please help me in creating the End Point...

Comment: Do you have HTTP Service Activation enabled on IIS ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that you have specified the following attribute on your method:

```
UriTemplate = "GetClassCode/{name}/{password}"
```

This means that your endpoint URL will actually be:

```
http://localhost/MyService.svc/GetClassCode/Himansu/hits@123
```

It would be better to not have the username and password as part of the URL, and just keep these as querystring parameters.  So, you could just have the following:

```
UriTemplate = "GetAuthenticatedUserData"
```

Your username and password would be passed in the same way, using querystring parameters.